# Extrapolating values into the future

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have set of data as follows:

```
1/3/15 245
2/3/15 246
3/3/15 260
4/3/15 261
5/3/15 267
6/3/15 270
7/3/15 278
8/3/15 290
9/3/15 314
```

With the values corresponding to the dates, (**Q:**) how can I predict what date the values; 350, 400, 450, 500, 550 and 600 will correspond to?

*Further note:*
I have graphed these values, got a linear (y=mx+b) trend line, and tried to 'calculate' the dates. Is there another/alternative method? I have been using Excel 2013.

Comment: It would be awesome if you entered your dates using [ISO date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) on SO to avoid confusion between months and days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=TREND($A$1:$A$9,$B$1:$B$9,D2)`

[image]

Also, `=FORECAST()` can do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`FORECAST` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FORECAST-function-8736aaa2-8a94-4358-b107-6cc0c8e90ffc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

```
2015-01-03  245 
2015-02-03  246 
2015-03-03  260 
2015-04-03  261 
2015-05-03  267 
2015-06-03  270 
2015-07-03  278 
2015-08-03  290 
2015-09-03  314 

2016-02-17  350 =FORECAST(B11,A$1:A$9,B$1:B$9)
2016-08-17  400 =FORECAST(B12,A$1:A$9,B$1:B$9)
2017-02-14  450 =FORECAST(B13,A$1:A$9,B$1:B$9)
2017-08-14  500 =FORECAST(B14,A$1:A$9,B$1:B$9)
2018-02-12  550 =FORECAST(B15,A$1:A$9,B$1:B$9)
2018-08-12  600 =FORECAST(B16,A$1:A$9,B$1:B$9)
```